# Sitecore 10 walkthrough - Get-SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String failing on init.ps1

Tags: installation, docker

I've come across the below error when running the initialisation script of the [Sitecore 10 with docker walkthrough](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html#UUID-f977232d-10af-7cda-da62-6f80c95e1a90_section-idm231883998424798) with license and password as parameters.

*.\init.ps1 -InitEnv -LicenseXmlPath "C:\source\licenses\sitecore\license.xml" -AdminPassword "TestPassword132435"*

**Output:**

```
Preparing your Sitecore Containers environment!
Importing SitecoreDockerTools...
Generating Traefik TLS certificate...
Using the local CA at "C:\Users\p.fonseca\AppData\Local\mkcert" ✨
The local CA is already installed in the system trust store! 
Note: Firefox support is not available on your platform. ℹ️    

Using the local CA at "C:\Users\p.fonseca\AppData\Local\mkcert" ✨

Created a new certificate valid for the following names 
 - "*.myproject.localhost"

Reminder: X.509 wildcards only go one level deep, so this won't match a.b.myproject.localhost ℹ️

The certificate is at "./_wildcard.myproject.localhost.pem" and the key at "./_wildcard.myproject.localhost-key.pem" ✅

Adding Windows hosts file entries...
Populating required .env file values...

Remove-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Users\P6D60~1.FON does not exist.
At C:\Users\p.fonseca\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreDockerTools\10.0.5\Public\Get-SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String.ps1:57 char:16
+     $pfxPath | Remove-Item
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Done!
```

The error occurs at the SITECORE_ID_CERTIFICATE step when SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String is called to fetch a certificate.

Would anyone more knowledgeable know what's happening under the hood and why C:\Users\P6D60~1.FON is the path being searched for?

Is there any parameter I should use to point SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String to another location? Or perhaps any additional step I am missing prior to running init.ps1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `.` in my user name which I suspect causes the issue. Cheers Mark Cassidy for pointing it out on slack.

Comment: I ended up commenting out the clean-up instruction that causes the issue. It's on Get-SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String.ps1 - "$pfxPath | Remove-Item". All it does is delete the pfx temporary file from your user folder which you can easily do manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, its looking for the path C:\Users\PAPIYA~1.DHA which does not exist.

I first uninstalled the SitecoreDockerTools module.
Changed the default directory of the SitecoreDockerTools module to a custom directory by making changes in the init.ps1 script, before setting the env file variables.

if (-not (Test-Path -Path 'C:\WindowsPowershellModules\SitecoreDockerTools\10.0.5\SitecoreDockerTools.psm1'))
{
Find-Module -Name 'SitecoreDockerTools' -Repository 'PSGallery' | Save-Module -Path 'C:\WindowsPowershellModules'
}

Import-Module -Name 'C:\WindowsPowershellModules\SitecoreDockerTools\10.0.5\SitecoreDockerTools.psm1' -Verbose

Downloaded mkcert from https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert/releases/download/v1.4.1/mkcert-v1.4.1-windows-amd64.exe as defined in the script, renamed it to mkcert.exe and copied in the path C:\Windows\System32

After rerunning the script, I still get an error at Get-SitecoreCertificateAsBase64String, but it populates the env file correctly and also executes the remaining steps to create the certs in the path docker-examples\getting-started\traefik\certs

[Poweshell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X9Ys.png)

Comment: You are correct, the process finishes as expected and everything is populated as it should. I decided to comment out that clean-up step having understood where the issue comes from.